# How to know which theme data changes what in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

In Flutter, it is pretty hard to find out what theme property changes what part of the app. For example, the background color of AppBar defaults to the primaryColor of the theme being used. I do not see this written anywhere in the documentation of the AppBar

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html

How are we supposed to know which theme property will change what parts of our widgets?

Comment: Specs are from  https://material.io/, at least it was. They reworked the website entirely so the specs used are not always up to date

Comment: @RémiRousselet Okay, but I wish if there was like a clear list of what theme property would change what part of the widget. I am trying to create a white AppBar with black text, but I'm struggling. This should not be so hard.

Comment: You can step inside the code if you truly need to.

Comment: @RémiRousselet I know you could, but would be really nice to have this kind of information in the documentation somewhere. Also, ThemeData.light does not change the AppBar text and icon color black.

Comment: @dshukertjr It seems like your issue is with the Flutter documentation. You should open an issue in the [Flutter Github repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new) if you feel the documentation is lacking.

Comment: @dshukertjr agree with you ... it makes use of ThemeData almost pointless. Ever widget pixel rendered uses a color, hopefully something from ThemeData, but which theme data? If I can't easily find out, or I have to look inside the code or I have to just override all theme data to get what I want ... I may as well hard code all the colors and avoid theming all together. I'll be raising a defect on the doco.

Comment: @mikeyman22 Glad to hear someone is struggling the same way! Hopefully the Flutter team changes this in the future.

Comment: @dshukertjr Well I logged an issue with flutter issue is here closed: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22925 but now merged with this main issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22773

Comment: @mikeyman22 Awesome!

Comment: Thank you @mikeyman22 ! The way built-in widgets use theme is extremely confusing.

Answer (score 3):

This answer was from @Aristidios - inappropriately deleted by @BhargavRao.

It isn't a great answer, but in 3 1/2 years this excellent question still doesn't have a better one :

---

If your still searching - Please checkout this great guide from Vivek Yadav - in his article he details each & everyone of the ThemeData parameters :

https://medium.com/flutter-community/themes-in-flutter-part-1-75f52f2334ea

---

And here is a short-hand copy of all the Theme properties:

```dart
ThemeData({
  Brightness brightness,
  MaterialColor primarySwatch,
  Color primaryColor,
  Brightness primaryColorBrightness,
  Color primaryColorLight,
  Color primaryColorDark,
  Color accentColor,
  Brightness accentColorBrightness,
  Color canvasColor,
  Color scaffoldBackgroundColor,
  Color bottomAppBarColor,
  Color cardColor,
  Color dividerColor,
  Color focusColor,
  Color hoverColor,
  Color highlightColor,
  Color splashColor,
  InteractiveInkFeatureFactory splashFactory,
  Color selectedRowColor,
  Color unselectedWidgetColor,
  Color disabledColor,
  Color buttonColor,
  ButtonThemeData buttonTheme,
  ToggleButtonsThemeData toggleButtonsTheme,
  Color secondaryHeaderColor,
  Color textSelectionColor,
  Color cursorColor,
  Color textSelectionHandleColor,
  Color backgroundColor,
  Color dialogBackgroundColor,
  Color indicatorColor,
  Color hintColor,
  Color errorColor,
  Color toggleableActiveColor,
  String fontFamily,
  TextTheme textTheme,
  TextTheme primaryTextTheme,
  TextTheme accentTextTheme,
  InputDecorationTheme inputDecorationTheme,
  IconThemeData iconTheme,
  IconThemeData primaryIconTheme,
  IconThemeData accentIconTheme,
  SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
  TabBarTheme tabBarTheme,
  TooltipThemeData tooltipTheme,
  CardTheme cardTheme,
  ChipThemeData chipTheme,
  TargetPlatform platform,
  MaterialTapTargetSize materialTapTargetSize,
  bool applyElevationOverlayColor,
  PageTransitionsTheme pageTransitionsTheme,
  AppBarTheme appBarTheme,
  BottomAppBarTheme bottomAppBarTheme,
  ColorScheme colorScheme,
  DialogTheme dialogTheme,
  FloatingActionButtonThemeData floatingActionButtonTheme,
  Typography typography,
  CupertinoThemeData cupertinoOverrideTheme,
  SnackBarThemeData snackBarTheme,
  BottomSheetThemeData bottomSheetTheme,
  PopupMenuThemeData popupMenuTheme,
  MaterialBannerThemeData bannerTheme,
  DividerThemeData dividerTheme,
  ButtonBarThemeData buttonBarTheme,
})
```